# How to legally watch Turkish and Kurdish TV over the internet?

Tags: turkey, television

I want channel-hopping.

So I don't want an app to watch one particular channel.

I am looking for a streaming provider which provides all channels.

It also has to be legal.

It's ok if it is not free.

Comment: I had voted to close this question as off-topic, but I have since retracted it since although it is a question about a specific country's TV services online, the only people interested in legally watching TV from other countries are basically expats. Also, I feel that if it was someone from the US or Western Europe that was asking, it would not garner off-topic votes as much as if it is not.

Comment: I asked at meta and they told me to post it here (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337728/what-is-the-right-site-to-ask-about-turkish-tv)

Answer (score 1):

Digiturk Play, which is an online streaming service by Turkey-based Digiturk, accepts subscriptions from foreign countries. TRT Kurdi, broadcasting in Kurdish, seems to be included.

As another option, most of channels officially have live broadcast on YouTube. [A basic search](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=canl%C4%B1%20yay%C4%B1n&sp=EgJAAQ%253D%253D) lists channels such as Habertürk, NTV, Star TV, ATV, Show TV and so on.